# How to set the "webdriver.chrome.driver" property with Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I am getting this error:

```
[01:10:42] E/launcher - The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
[01:10:42] E/launcher - WebDriverError: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
```

I need to set the `webdriver.chrome.driver` property, but I can't find any docs on how to do this with Protractor, does anyone know?

If I had this to my protractor.conf.js:

```
 chrome:{
    driver:  process.env.CDT_CHROMEDRIVER || '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
  },
```

then I get this error:

```
unknown error: no chrome binary at /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Comment: note that I need to get this running in Docker. Using `webdriver-manager` works fine.

Answer (score 12):

**Case 1** When you set DirectConnet to true in protractor conf file

Option 1: set in protractor conf file

```
exports.config = {
  chromeDriver: './node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver'
};
```

Note: If use relative path, it relatived to the config file folder

Option 2: pass-in in protractor command line, it will overwrite the one in conf file.

```
protractor conf.js --chromeDriver='./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver'
```

Note: If use relative path, it relative to the foler where command executed under, calculated by `process.cwd()`

**Case 2** When you set selenuimAddress to local/remote selenium server

Option 1: use npm package `webdriver-manager` to help to update and start selenium server, it can calculate the webdriver path automatically, no need you to tell where is.

Option 2: start selenium server by java command and specify 
`-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=absolute path of chromedriver`

**Case 3** When you set seleniumAddress to selenium grid
the only chance you can specify `webdriver.chrome.driver` is when execute register cmd to register selenium node to selenium hub, you can't do anything in other place.