# how can I set chome binary location with webdriver manager

Tags: protractor

Currently my webdriver manager is picking chrome location from some webex plugin. I have chrome installed on my machine and not sure how to point the webdriver manger to it. I am **not** looking to set chromedriver, but the chrome binary location

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can set chrome binary in protractor

```
capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
          'binary': 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
            'args': ["--headless", "--log-level=3", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1280x1024"]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you can find the answer from the below link
[How to set the "webdriver.chrome.driver" property with Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413384/how-to-set-the-webdriver-chrome-driver-property-with-protractor). May i know the reason to set chrome binary location with webdriver manger?.In Protractor by default Test Case will be run in Chrome browser.